# glm non-linear prediction

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression, prediction

I'd like to predict users growth for the next period of time based on existing growth.  Below is the code and the result.  The problem is that ggplot glm is a linear regression model.  So, the growth is overly generous.  Could I get a better fitting prediction somehow?  Thanks

```
date <- c(as.Date("2016-4-1"), as.Date("2016-4-2"), as.Date("2016-4-3"), as.Date("2016-4-4"), as.Date("2016-4-5"), as.Date("2016-4-6"), as.Date("2016-4-7"), as.Date("2016-4-14"), as.Date("2016-4-21"), as.Date("2016-4-28"), as.Date("2016-5-5"), as.Date("2016-5-12"), as.Date("2016-5-19"))
users <- c(44367531, 55398776, 61215790, 65289569, 70244719, 72920785, 74751819, 87910607, 96620788, 103815241, 110267109, 116033006, 121007902)
ds <- data.frame(date, users)

model <- glm(users ~ date, data=df)
df.new <- data.frame(date=c(as.Date("2016-06-01"), as.Date("2016-07-01"), as.Date("2016-08-01"), as.Date("2016-09-01"), as.Date("2016-10-01")))
df.new$future <- predict(model, newdata=df.new)

g1 <- ggplot(merge(x=df, y=df.new, by="date", all=TRUE), aes(date))
g1 <- g1 + geom_line(aes(y=users, color="users"))
    g1 <- g1 + geom_line(aes(y=future, color="future"))
g1 <- g1 + labs(title="User Growth", y="Total Users", x="Date")
g1 <- g1 + scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks("1 month"), labels=date_format("%Y-%m-%d"), limits=c(as.Date("2016-04-01"), as.Date("2017-01-01")))
g1 <- g1 + scale_y_continuous(name="Total Users", labels=comma)
g1 <- g1 + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
g1
```

[image]

Comment: You should use `ggplot` as a plotting tool, not a modeling tool. Taking a log of your response variable would almost certainly improve things. (Or using `family = gaussian(link = 'log')` with your `glm`.)

Comment: Your code produces a different plot (with a more reasonable fitted line) on my machine. Which version of `ggplot2` are you using?

Comment: take log(users) instead of users

Comment: ggplot2_2.0.0, @Gregor would you mind adding a full example as an answer?  I need some more help figuring out how this might be done.

Comment: @Gregor I've extracted the predictions out.  Using family = gaussian(link = 'log') doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? `glm(users ~ date, data=df, family = gaussian(link = 'log'))` works fine for me (though, looking at it, it's still a pretty poor model).

Comment: But focus on getting a model that fits the data you have before you try to extrapolate and predict.